# Reuse the result of Where Step in projection

Tags: gremlin

I got a sample graph which can be constructed with following DSL:

```
g.addV('A').property(id, 'A1')
g.addV('B').property(id, 'B1').addE('B').from(V('A1'))
g.addV('B').property(id, 'B2').addE('B').from(V('A1'))
g.addV('C').property(id, 'C1').addE('C').from(V('B1'))
g.addV('C').property(id, 'C2').addE('C').from(V('B2'))
g.addV('BB').property(id, 'BB1').property('age', 2).addE('BB').from(V('B2'))
g.addV('BB').property(id, 'BB2').addE('BB').from(V('B2'))
g.addV('BB').property(id, 'BB3').addE('BB').from(V('B1'))
```

I wanna to traverse from vertices with Label A, through edges with Label 'B', 'C', and output all the path with 'BB' attached with each 'B' vertex, I can manage to get the result use:

```
g.V().hasLabel('A').as('a').
out('B').as('b').
out('C').as('c').
project('shop', 'product', 'spec', 'device').
by(select('a').valueMap(true)).
by(select('b').valueMap(true)).
by(select('b').out('BB').valueMap(true).fold()).
by(select('c').valueMap(true))
```

Then I ran into another scenario, I have to filter 'B' vertex with condition of 'BB', which can be achieved by:

```
g.V().hasLabel('A').as('a').
out('B').where(out('BB').has('age', 2)).as('b').
out('C').as('c').
project('shop', 'product', 'spec', 'device').
by(select('a').valueMap(true)).
by(select('b').valueMap(true)).
by(select('b').out('BB').has('age', 2).valueMap(true).fold()).
by(select('c').valueMap(true))
```

My question is: **Can i reuse the result of Where Step instead of filter 'BB' again in Projection ?**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of your approach, no, you cannot simply re-use the results of the traversal within the `where()`. The reason is fairly straightforward in that the `where()` doesn't fully iterate the result - it seeks a what amounts to a `hasNext()` to detect the first item in the `Iterator`.

So, depending on the selectivity of `has('age',2)` and the fact that `where()` is really just looking for one result, the cost of that traversal may not be terribly expensive and you could possibly live with it traversing twice. If it is "expensive" and your graph supports some sort of vertex-centric index you might denormalize "age" to the "BB" edge and then just do `where(outE('BB').has('age',2))`.

Another way to possibly look at it would be to simplify your traversal a bit. Since you use step labels, why not eliminate `project()` and directly traverse "BB":

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('A').as('shop').
......1>   out('B').as('product').
......2>   out('BB').has('age', 2).as('spec').
......3>   select('product').
......4>   out('C').as('device').
......5>   select('shop', 'product', 'spec', 'device').
......6>     by(valueMap(true))
==>[shop:[id:A1,label:A],product:[id:B2,label:B],spec:[id:BB1,label:BB,age:[2]],device:[id:C2,label:C]]
```

That's a much more readable traversal, but makes some assumptions about your data and the shape of your result that may not quite match what you were doing with `project()`. I suppose that with a fair bit of Gremlin collection manipulation you could bring the grouping around "spec" back, but then the readability starts to fall apart.

The following approach seems sacrifices some readability to do the `out('BB').has('age',2)` just once:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('A').as('shop').
......1>   out('B').as('product').
......2>   project('s').
......3>     by(out('BB').has('age', 2).valueMap(true).fold()).as('spec').
......4>   where(select('s').unfold()).
......5>   select('product').
......6>   out('C').as('device').
......7>   select('shop', 'product', 'spec', 'device').
......8>     by(valueMap(true)).
......9>     by(valueMap(true)).
.....10>     by(select('s')).
.....11>     by(valueMap(true)) 
==>[shop:[id:A1,label:A],product:[id:B2,label:B],spec:[[id:BB1,label:BB,age:[2]]],device:[id:C2,label:C]]
```

If I were looking at this for the first time, I'd immediately wonder what the point of lines 2-4 where doing. It's not clear that the whole point of a the `Map` produce by `project('s')` is to fully realize the results of `out('BB').has('age', 2)` so that they can be used at line 4 to filter those traversers away. I don't think we'd often recommend this approach except that in this case you need to realize the entire result no matter what. If there is even one result then you need all of them, so may as well grab them all up front.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I prefer the latter solution as i missed to mention that, i need all the matched BB values packed in a single path from A->B->C.